# Storing Queries in MYSQL database giving errors when using line breaks/whitespace

Tags: mysql

I have a few queries that are stored in a MYSQL database that are then pulled from the database and run in routines.  The queries run fine when I insert them into the database using no line breaks/tabs but when I try to run the same query formatted nicely (which I want to do in case I need to update the queries later) I get an error.  Here is an example of one that works and one that doesn't (they are the same as far as the code)

```
IF(@last_ranking <> formula, @current_rankings := @current_rankings + 1, @current_rankings)  AS rank, @last_ranking := formula, prequery.team, prequery.formula FROM (select @current_rankings := 0) sqlvars, (SELECT team, SUM(formula) AS formula FROM (SELECT g.home_team AS team, SUM(CASE WHEN t.team_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE g.home_wins END) AS formula FROM games g LEFT JOIN _top_10 AS t ON g.away_team = t.team_id WHERE g.season = ? AND g.completed = 1 GROUP BY team UNION ALL SELECT g.away_team AS team, SUM(CASE WHEN t2.team_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE g.away_wins END) AS formula FROM games g LEFT JOIN _top_10 AS t2 ON g.home_team = t2.team_id WHERE g.season = ? AND g.completed = 1 GROUP BY team) AS Alias,(SELECT @current_rankings := 0, @last_ranking := 0) r GROUP BY team ORDER BY formula DESC ) prequery;
```

and

```
        IF(@last_ranking <> formula, @current_rankings := @current_rankings + 1, @current_rankings)  AS rank, 
         @last_ranking := formula, 
         prequery.team, 
         prequery.formula 
 FROM    (select @current_rankings := 0) sqlvars, 
         (SELECT     team, 
                     SUM(formula) AS formula 
         FROM        (SELECT     g.home_team AS team, 
                                 SUM(CASE WHEN t.team_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE g.home_wins END) AS formula 
                     FROM        games g 
                     LEFT JOIN   _top_10 AS t ON g.away_team = t.team_id 
                     WHERE       g.season = ? AND 
                                 g.completed = 1 
                     GROUP BY    team
         UNION ALL   SELECT      g.away_team AS team, 
                                 SUM(CASE WHEN t2.team_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE g.away_wins END) AS formula 
                     FROM        games g 
                     LEFT JOIN   _top_10 AS t2 ON g.home_team = t2.team_id 
                     WHERE       g.season = ? AND 
                                 g.completed = 1 
                     GROUP BY    team) AS Alias,
         (SELECT @current_rankings := 0, @last_ranking := 0) r 
 GROUP BY team 
 ORDER BY formula DESC ) prequery;
```

What's the deal?  Is there a way to store the information with whitespace in the database but remove line breaks/tabs/unnecessary whitespace on the fly when I run the queries?

The error I'm getting is

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 18
```

Comment: can u pls share the error message also

Comment: @cjg I updated the question to reflect the error I'm getting